# How to set min/max values for an integer, where `++` and `--` and general math obeys the limits you set, in c++?

Tags: c++, integer, operator-overloading, integer-overflow

Rather than litter my code with a ton of `if` statements, I would like to know a clean method for setting limits on an integer, that will still wrap its value when iterating over those limits.

So for example,

```
int i(9998);
setMinMax(i,-27315, 10000); // Absolute Zero - Boiling Point of water
i++; // ==  9999
i++; // ==  10000
i++; // == -27315
```

If the min-max values can be dynamic, that would be ideal. I do not mind making a new type, or operator overloading. I just want to avoid having to do something like this:

```
int i = foo();
int j = bar();
int min(-27315);
int max(10000);
i += j;
     if (i==min-1) {i=max}
else if (i==max+1) {i=min}
else if (i>max) {i=min+(i-max)}
// more stupid code
```

Thanks.

Comment: As the question is about C++, please don't tag [tag:c]

Answer (score 5):

This can be done, but not with primitive `int`s. You'll need to implement your own class type that overloads various arithmetic operators in order to look and feel just like an int. Here's one way you could achieve this:

```
#include <limits> // for numeric_limits

struct RangedInt {
private:
    int m_min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int m_max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int m_val = 0;
public:
    RangedInt(int value = 0) : m_val(value) {}

    void setMinMax(int min, int max){
        m_min = min;
        m_max = max;
        m_val = std::min(std::max(m_val, m_min), m_max);
    }

    // pre-increment
    RangedInt& operator++(){
        m_val++;
        if (m_val > m_max) m_val = m_min;
        return *this;
    }

    // post-increment
    RangedInt operator++(int){
        RangedInt tmp {*this}; // create temporary with old value
        operator++(); // perform increment
        return tmp; // return temporary
    }

    // pre-decrement
    RangedInt& operator--(){
        m_val--;
        if (m_val < m_min) m_val = m_max;
        return *this;
    }

    // post-decrement
    RangedInt operator--(int){
        RangedInt tmp {*this}; // create temporary with old value
        operator--(); // perform decrement
        return tmp; // return temporary
    }

    // this can be extended to implement the following operators
    RangedInt operator+(const RangedInt& x);
    RangedInt operator+(int x);
    RangedInt operator-(const RangedInt& x);
    RangedInt operator-(int x);
    RangedInt& operator+=(const RangedInt& x);
    RangedInt& operator+=(int x);
    RangedInt& operator-=(const RangedInt& x);
    RangedInt& operator-=(int x);
    // and lots more, for *, /, unary +/-, etc...

    // convenient conversion to int:
    explicit operator int(){
        return m_val;
    }
};
```

The above code now lets you write the following:

```
RangedInt i = 9998;
i.setMinMax(-27135, 10000);
std::cout << (int)i << '\n'; // 9998
i++;
std::cout << (int)i << '\n'; // 9999
i++;
std::cout << (int)i << '\n'; // 10000
i++;
std::cout << (int)i << '\n'; // -27135
```

This method can be extended with templates to work for any numeric type and not just `int`, and you could also turn the minimum and maximum values into template parameters, if they're known at compile time and memory footprint is a concern.

Comment: You're welcome. It was so clearly visible to me I didn't think I needed to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Jonathan Müller's `type_safe` [library](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe) and associated [blog post](https://foonathan.net/blog/2016/10/11/type-safe.html). It provides a framework to do (among many other things) what you're looking for here.